# Controller Action won't accept JSON post using JS Fetch API even with [FromBody] and Content-Type set

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, fetch-api

All other posts I've read haven't helped me on this topic (telling me to put `[FromBody]` or set the content type in the header).

My js function is:

```
async function GetEditModalHTML(productPriceGroupID) {
    const data = {
        ProductPriceGroupID: productPriceGroupID
    }
    const response = await fetch('/promotions/productprice/edit', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    
    return await response.text();
}
```

And the function definition in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromBody] int productPriceGroupID)
```

Debugging in Rider I know the action is properly being called. In chromes network tab I can see the payload as:

[image]

But no matter what I try to do, the value of `productPriceGroupID` is always 0. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Class the pass the data

```
    class ProductDetails{
public int productPriceGroupID {get;set;}
}
```

then assign

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromBody] ProductDetails productPriceGroupID)
```

Comment: Thank you - this does work. Is there no other way than having to wrap it in a class? Seems like extra boilerplate.

Comment: then url must be http://localhost:8000/edit?productPriceGroupID=5